# How to overwrite content in text file? (edit items)

Tags: c

My problem would be, how can i edit the string value when i input my item code let's say for example: (this is inside a text file called gst.txt)

```
AG001;July biscuits;5.35;90
BG001;Maximu Bun;3.50;20 
BG002;Lamli Burger;4.60;15
CG001;TTT Candy;4.00;42
CG002;Cappuccino;7.80;30
CG003;Queenz Cakes;14.00;5
DG001;Donkey Donuts;3.80;24
DG002;French Fries;4.30;11
```

the segment is follow as: (itemcode);(itemname);(itemprice);(itemquantity)

When i entered the item code of `AG001`. I have option to choose, whether to edit the item name, item price of item quantity. When i choose the item name option, i entered the new name for the item. How can i overwrite the existing `July biscuits` into something like `Gardenia` while only change that segment of the text file?

Here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char itemcode[10];
char gst[256];
char gstcode[10], gstname[50];
char gstprice[10];
char gstquantity[5];
char selection[5];
char newname[50], newprice[10], newquantity[5];

int main()
{
    FILE* fgst;
    fgst = fopen("gst.txt", "r+");

    while (strcmp(itemcode, "-1") != 0) {

        printf("Enter item code to be edited <-1 to exit>: ");
        scanf("%s", itemcode);

        if (strcmp(itemcode, "-1") == 0)
            break;

        if (strcmp(itemcode, "AG001") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "BG001") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "BG002") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "CG001") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "CG002") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "CG003") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "DG001") == 0 || strcmp(itemcode, "DG002") == 0) {

            while (fgets(gst, 256, fgst) != NULL) {

                sscanf(gst, "%5[^;];%29[^;];%10[^;];%5[^;]", gstcode, gstname, gstprice, gstquantity);

                if (strcmp(itemcode, gstcode) == 0) {

                    printf("Enter <1> to edit item name, <2> for price, <3> for quantity: ");
                    scanf("%s", selection);

                    if (strcmp(selection, "1") == 0) {

                        printf("Enter the new item name: ");
                        scanf("%s", newname);
                        fprintf(fgst, "%s;%s;%s;%s", gstcode, newname, gstprice, gstquantity);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (strcmp(selection, "2") == 0) {

                        printf("Enter the new item price: ");
                        scanf("%s", newprice);
                        fprintf(fgst, "%s;%s;%s;%s", gstcode, gstname, newprice, gstquantity);
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (strcmp(selection, "3") == 0) {

                        printf("Enter the new item quantity: ");
                        scanf("%s", newquantity);
                        fprintf(fgst, "%s;%s;%s;%s", gstcode, gstname, gstprice, newquantity);
                        break;
                    }

                    else {
                        printf("Invalid input.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            printf("Item not found.\n");
            printf("Re-enter the correct item code.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way, and almost the only way or the only good way is to create a temporary file, write the modified content to it and rename it.

Comment: Can i use struct function and structure to edit the items? How do i create a temporary file? I just want to change that part of segment like overwrite it with the input i entered.

Comment: You _can_ overwrite the part of the file as long as the replacement material is exactly the same length as the original — you use `fseek()`, and maybe `ftell()` and related functions.  If the replacement text is shorter, you could blank pad to the original length (or use some other pad character).  If the replacement text is longer, you're snookered — you can't move data around in a file without copying the whole file.  The general solution, therefore, is to copy the file with modifications to a new file (as others said).

Comment: So, the only, and simplest solution would be copy the file with modifications and write into a new file using 'w' ? which have everything but the only changes would the editted segment string?

Comment: @OliverSim yes, exactly

Comment: Then it comes to the part of algorithm that i do not understand. For example, if i entered BG002 and i want to change the name into 'Gardenia' how can i copy everything above it and the line itself and below into a 'w' text file?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by iharob, you will probably need to create a temporary file, write the modified content to it and rename it. It will work for most cases.

However, If this involves thousands or hundreds of thousands of entries, this method is not practical. Then, you will need a different file storage structure. Each field should have a maximum limit and be padded upto it's limit. The size of each line will become equal in each case, and can be easily replaced by another line.

e.g.

```
AG001;July biscuits      ;005.035;090
BG001;Maximu Bun         ;003.050;020 
BG002;Lamli Burger       ;004.060;015
CG001;TTT Candy          ;004.000;042
```

Comment: I've done it already. And it seems that writing into a new file with editted variable works. How do i rename the text file?

Comment: You can rename with function `rename` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rename.htm

Answer (score 0):

I made an simplified example to show you how you can use structs and a 'temporary' file to achieve your goal.

This is a shortend structure of your items. For simplicity i only used the item code and the item name:

```
typedef struct
{
  char item_code[10];
  char item_name[50];
} item;
```

First of all i would suggest to write a read an write fuction so you can easily write this struct to an file and read it from it. Something like this:

```
void write_items_to_file(FILE* fp, item* items, size_t size)
{
  if (!fp)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "File not open!\n");
    return;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    fprintf(fp, "%s;%s;\n", items[i].item_code, items[i].item_name);
  }
}

size_t read_items_from_file(FILE* fp, item* items, size_t max)
{
  if (!fp)
  {
    printf("File not open!\n");
    return -1;
  }

  char line[MAX_LEN];
  size_t current_item = 0;
  while (fgets(line, MAX_LEN, fp) && current_item < max)
  {
    if (sscanf(line, "%5[^;];%50[^;];", (items[current_item].item_code), (items[current_item].item_name)) != 2) // change '2' to the amount of atributes of item
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Wrong internal file organization!\n");
      return -2;
    }
    current_item++;
  }
  return current_item;
}
```

Now we got this, lets face the changing part. Assume we have a file with two items:

```
AG001;July biscuits;
BG001;Maximu Bun;
```

Now we can use the `read_items_from_file` function to get the items. If You now want to change `July biscuits` to `Gardenia` we can use `strncmp` to find the item with the name `July biscuits` and replace it.

When we're finished with editing the items we write the to another file e.g. `"items.txt.tmp"` using the `write_items_to_file` function. After that we `rename` the 'temporary' file to the original file und thus replaced the name of the desired item in the original file. This is as others pointed out the easiest approach.

Here ist the complete main of the scenario i described:

```
int main()
{
  FILE *fp = fopen("items.txt", "r");
  item items_read[2]; 

  size_t read_values = read_items_from_file(fp, items_read, 2);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < read_values; i++)
  {
    if (strncmp(items_read[i].item_name, "July biscuits", 50) == 0)
    {
      strncpy(items_read[i].item_name,"Gardenia", 50);
    }
  }

  if (fp)
  {
    fclose(fp);
  }

  // now create a new file
  fp = fopen("items.txt.tmp", "w");
  if (fp)
  {
    write_items_to_file(fp, items_read, 2);
    fclose(fp);

    // now "move" the temp file to the original file using 'rename'
    rename("items.txt.tmp", "items.txt");
  }
}
```

**Note:** Of course you have to change the `item struct` and the read and write functions according to your requirements.